# mysql php insert query

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am beginner in php & mysql.

I want query to gabia DB. I have an error 1064 and I do not know the cause.

this is my query

```
$sql = "insert into FileList_PK_DB(PK_CorpName,PK_Code,up_date,username,Null) 
values ('".trim($_POST[corpname])."', '".trim($_POST[corpcode])."',  '".trim($_POST[FDDate])."', '".trim($_POST[FDmember])."', '".trim($_POST[workcont])."')";
```

this is my result

```
insert into FileList_PK_DB(PK_CorpName,PK_Code,up_date,username,Null) values ('TEAM', 'h0002', '2017-11-28', 'C0001', 'qwer')
```

> 1064 : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Null) values ('TEAM', 'h0002', '2017-11-28', 'C0001', 'qwer')'
>   at line 1

i find google but... i could not solve it

please help me

Comment: do you have `Null` name column?

Comment: oh my god thanks  genius

Comment: `NULL` is reserved keyword in Mysql. To escape it use back tick (`) character.

Comment: You are open to SQL injections, parameterize the query.